# Is it possible to rewrite this Haskell function using guards with no case-of?

Tags: haskell

I have this Haskell function that uses "case of", but I am trying to figure out if it's possible to rewrite this function using guards("|") and not "case of". Is it possible ? Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
lefQ :: Ord a => LOL a -> Lang a -> Lang a
lefQ (LOL i xs) [] = []
lefQ (LOL i xs) (LOL j y:ys) = case stripPrefix xs y of
                    Nothing -> leftq (LOL i xs) ys
                    Just zs -> (LOL (j-i) zs):lefQ (LOL i xs) ys
```

Comment: (Regular) guards can only check boolean values, while pattern matching can instead discriminate values in all algebraic types -- not merely `Bool`. There is a way to convert your code to use (regular) guards exploiting partial functions, but that's an anti-pattern which should be avoided. One should always prefer (exhaustive) pattern matching to calling functions that might throw an error and crash the whole program.

Answer (score 4):

You can work with a *pattern guard*, so:

```
lefQ :: Ord a => LOL a -> Lang a -> Lang a
lefQ (LOL i xs) [] = []
lefQ (LOL i xs) (LOL j y:ys)
    | Just zs <- stripPrefix xs y = (LOL (j-i) zs): lefQ (LOL i xs) ys
    | otherwise = leftq (LOL i xs) ys
```